# Как правильно настроить ajax?

Tags: yii2

вот часть экшена отвечающая за ajax запрос

```
$module=$this->module;
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
  $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
    if(!empty($post)){
      return $this->render('create', [
        'found'  =>null,
      ]);
    }else{
      $get=Yii::$app->request->get();
       foreach ($module->models as $value){
            if($value['class']===$get['className']){
                $found =$value;
                break;
            }
       }
       return $this->render('create', [
           'found'  =>$found,
       ]);
    }
}
```

вот представление

```
<?php var_dump($found); ?>
```

вот скрипт js

```
$(".sortable-ui").on('click','.wells .showDropFile',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var id = $(this).parents('li.wells').attr('data-id');
        var className = $(this).parents('li.wells').attr('data-model');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url:url,
            data:"id="+id+"&className="+className,
            success: function(data){
                alert(url);
            }
        });
    });
```

но в представлении что до  после работы `ajax` скрипта отображается `null` 
 но в представлении что до  после работы ajax скрипта отображается null, Почему не результат цикла

```
foreach ($module->models as $value){
            if($value['class']===$get['className']){
                $found =$value;
                break;
            }
       }
```

или я что то не так понимаю ?

Comment: по-моему вы запутались в запросах, для чего в экшене `if(!empty($post))`?

Comment: @Blacknife там два запроса один гет который передает параметры для создания инпут файл для загрузки картинки и пост для передачи картинки. Где я запутался ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вместо

```
  $post=Yii::$app->request->post();
if(!empty($post)){
```

попробуйте

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){
```

Потому как Вы не понятно почему решили, что Yii::$app->request->post() вернет Вам пустое значение
Как следствие Всегда срабатывает `'found'  =>null,`
И еще, раз уж ajax, то вероятно не `$this->render()`, а `$this->renderAjax()`

Answer (score 0):

***Если попробовать так?***

```
if($value['class'] == $get['className']){
   $found =$value;
   break;
}
```

Вообще, посмотри что выдает тебе, без условного опрератора:

```
foreach ($module->models as $value){
   $found =$value;
   break;
}
```

Comment: да нормально выдаст. Поверь там все нормально и все суть именно в этом операторе там приходит массив